# Find the elements $[x]_{50}$ such that $[15]_{50}\cdot[x]_{50} = [0]_{50}$

Tags: ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences, congruence-relations

I'm given the integer residue ring $R = \Bbb Z/50\Bbb Z$

I'm wanting to find all elements $[x]_{50}$ such that
$[15]_{50}\cdot[x]_{50} = [0]_{50}$.

Because the prime factorizations of $15$ and $50$ are $15:3,5$ and $50:2,5,5$, wouldn't any multiple of $10$ work for $[15]_{50}\cdot[x]_{50} = [0]_{50}$, making $x=\{[10]_{50},[20]_{50},[30]_{50},[40]_{50}\}$? Do I only want to only include numbers in the complete canonical residue system? Did I write out the solutions correctly? Am I supposed to include $[0]_{50}$? I thought that because it's not a zero divisor that it doesn't get included.

Comment: What about $[0]_{50}$?

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should include it because I thought that I am only supposed to include zero divisors, and zero is not a zero divisor and more of it's own thing.

Comment: Yes, $50\mid 15x \iff 10\mid 3x\iff 10\mid x\ \ $

Comment: Well, you didn't restrict $x$ to be a zero divisor in your question, so, as worded, $[0]_{50}$ is an answer.  If you want to restrict your question, you should edit it.

Comment: @michaelBurr Ohhhhhhh. I think I just assumed it was only zero divisors. That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @michaelburr thanks. I think that is probably the best way for me to express it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

What integer(s) $\;n\;$ can you come up with such that $\;15n\;$ is a multiple of $\;50\;$ ...?

Comment: n=10, 20, 30, 40. Am I supposed to include 0? I thought that because it isn't a zero divisor that you don't include it.

Comment: Am I supposed to write it as x=10k where k is in the set of integers, or should I be more specific and write the elements in the complete canonical residue system?

Comment: @eulersnumber I'm not your teacher: I can't know that. You can try the canonical residues: $\;0,10,20,30,40\;$ , and **also** remark that *any* integer of the form $\;10k\;$ will work...

Comment: Yes not my teacher. I was just asking about proper notation for expressing answers to the solution. Thanks.